# Blender's Sound actuator 3D sound without pitch change

Tags: game-engine, audio

I want to use a certain sound in my game, but the object that is using it is moving quite fast. If it passes by the camera the pitch changes dramatically. I know that this is a natural effect, but it's pitch changes way too much. It's not realistic anymore.

Is there a way to either remove the effect or decrease it without changing any other 3D sound setting. I would still like to be able to hear where the object is coming from through my headphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember if it works in the game engine, but this is where you're meant to be able to adjust this (the Doppler box under scene settings)

[image]